# Does the ColdFusion jnbridge license allow (command line) use of jnbproxy?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

The ColdFusion documentation describes how you can [use jnbproxy from the command line](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7fe4.html). However even my simplest attempts to run it via the command line (developer edition) fail with the error "Invalid or expired license". The GUI tool works perfectly.

Has anyone successfully used `jnbproxy` from the command line? Or could this be an error in the documentation?

Comment: Have you tried a licensed edition of CF rather than developer edition? (By the way I'd love to know what your use case is)

Comment: Nope. I was hoping someone else had ;) I cannot try that until later in the week. I want to generate a .jar file of proxies (because CF keeps missing some referenced classes). The command line tool allows you to feed in a file of class names. The gui tool does not even support using wildcards, not until version 6 I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you add the "/cf" option in the command line? Check the details at [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7fe4.html)

Comment: Silly me. No, I used the sample code as a base (which does *not* include the flag btw) and completely overlooked it. I will give it a try later. But I am confident you are right about that being the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should work, according to the documentation you can use it from the command line

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=dotNet_09.html

Comment: Yep, but as I mentioned it does not work for me :/ So I wanted to know if anyone has ever successfully used it (and under what version). Trying to figure out if it is a configuration problem or just an error in the docs.